# Laravel - How to access stored image from Google Cloud Storage using PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, laravel-5.8

In one of my Laravel apps, I want to show customer images that are stored in **Google Cloud Storage**. The Customer image name is stored in the local database. All of the information available in my hand is:

Base URL: gs:// < my_custom_url >/
Customer Image Stored in: customer/images/
File Name in DB: customer_one.jpg [The image is available in Google Cloud Storage]

Now my question is how can I retrieve/fetch that image from **Google Cloud Storage** and show the image in **HTML**  tag?

Can anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say easiest way to retrieve images from google cloud storage is install package for that.

Personally I'd recommend you to use **Laravel Google Cloud Storage** package.

I will write you basic steps

- First you install the package

`composer require superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage`

- Second under your filesystems define required credentials

```
'gcs' => [
    'driver' => 'gcs',
    'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'your-project-id'),
    'key_file' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE', null), // optional: /path/to/service-account.json
    'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET', 'your-bucket'),
    'path_prefix' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PATH_PREFIX', null), // optional: /default/path/to/apply/in/bucket
    'storage_api_uri' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_URI', null), // see: Public URLs below
    'visibility' => 'public', // optional: public|private
],
```

Afterwards you can just define storage driver and path to retrieve your images.
Assuming that you have an image `foo.jpg` under `customer/images` folder

```
$disk = Storage::disk('gcs');
$url = $disk->url('customer/images/foo.jpg');
>>> http://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/customer/images/foo.jpg
```

or if you define `path_prefix` as in default you can retrieve images by just doing

```
$disk = Storage::disk('gcs');
$url = $disk->url('foo.jpg');
>>> http://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/customer/images/foo.jpg
```

Will give you images from your google cloud storage.

For more information check:

https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

Your images are stored in gs:// < my_custom_url >/ ?
What is this location - customer/images/ ?

Comment: nope.
my_custom_url: devs.xyz.com

Here is a dummy URL:
gs://devs.xyz.com/customer/images/12/foo.jpg/