# Deploying Laravel app to Google App Engine

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy my Laravel 7.29.3 app to Google App Engine Standard environment. I have followed the guided located here https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard. However, I get a View[Welcome] not found error when I view my deployment. My app.yaml file looks like below:

```
runtime: php72

env_variables:
  ## Put production environment variables here.
  APP_KEY: YOUR_APP_KEY
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
```

Its a very simple yaml file as I am only using the welcome view and a route to a contact page. Please note that I am not using any database in this version. Please see my routing below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('contact', 'ContactFormController@ContactForm');
```

I also reviewed this question here: [View [welcome] not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442083/view-welcome-not-found) but I am still getting the same error. From my understanding of @sllopis comment, I need to put my welcome.blade.php file in a layouts folder. I have done that, and still get the same error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: it does not go in the layouts folder, if that was the case you would have to reference that view as `layouts.welcome`

Comment: I know it trivial, but I don't see it in your app.yaml. Are you sure you did replacement of `YOUR_APP_KEY` from point 2 of mentioned tutorial? please DO NOT post it, just check and confirm

Comment: @lagbox, where do you think it would go?

Comment: @vitooh, yes I have put the app key in my yaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. First you can add handlers to your app.yaml file. It should look like below:

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js))$
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)$

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto

env_variables:
  ## Put production environment variables here.
  APP_KEY: YOUR_APP_KEY
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57822141/2251229

Then you can update your config/filesystems.php file. You can add a new file system as per the sample provided below.

```
'gcs' => [
    'driver' => 'gcs',
    'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'your-project-id'),
    'key_file' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE', null), // optional: /path/to/service-account.json
    'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET', 'your-bucket'),
    'path_prefix' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PATH_PREFIX', null), // optional: /default/path/to/apply/in/bucket
    'storage_api_uri' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_URI', null), // see: Public URLs below
    'visibility' => 'public', // optional: public|private
],
```

And then update your default file system like so:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'gcs'),
```

Install the Laravel Google Cloud Storage package using the below command:

```
composer require superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177913/2251229

From here you can do your `gcloud app deploy`, and `gcloud app browse`. If you get further errors, do `php artisan config:clear`. This should clear any cached configurations.